# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and doing this as a project for school.  Here's the code I've written

```
public static void main(String args[])
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SleepCounter extends JFrame {
  private JPanel panel;
  private JLabel messageLabel;
  private JTextField sleepTextField;
  private JTextField sleepAnswerField;
  private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;
  private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;
  public SleepCounter() {
    setTitle("Sleep Counter");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buildPanel();
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  private void buildPanel() {
    dailyLabel = new JLabel("Enter Sleep " + "in hours");
    hourTextField = new JTextField(10);
    CalcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    CalcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(dailyLabel);
    panel.add(sleepTextField);
    panel.add(CalcButton);
    panel.add(sleepAnswerField);
  }
  private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformer(ActionEvent e) {
      String input;
      int total;
      input = sleepTextField.getText();
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++); {
        input += total;
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total amount of sleep for " + (i + 1) + "days is" + total);
      if (int i > 7) {
        double avg = (total / 7);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The avg amount of sleep for 7 days is" + avg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running I get an error message saying:

```
Error: Could not find or laod main class Graduation Project.
```

I've done a search of this site and checked the answers as much as I know how.  I would appreciate any help that you offer.

Comment: Are you using a IDE (netbeans, eclipse, jcreator) to code this class?

Answer (score 1):

You  have put  main method  outside the class

```
 public class  YourClass
 {
  public static void main(String args[])
   {  
   }
  }
```

place it inside   and remember  you cant put anything before these  imports

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  I'll work in these changes and hopefully that will fix the problem.  And I really appreciate the help.  Hopefully I'll be experienced enough in the future to help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell from your formatting. But if you're going to be running a class called "Graduation", you're code is going to have to look like this:

```
public class Graduation{ 


  public static void main (String[] args){
  }

}
```

You need the Graduation class, and it needs to have a main method that conforms to that. It's not clear from your example that your methods are actually inside a class. Is it compiling?